# Why does Chrome squish my text when I flex a parent container?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-chrome-squishing-text

```
<mat-accordion [multi]="false">
    <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header expandedHeight="116px" collapsedHeight="116px">
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%">
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <span fxFlex="50%">header 1</span>
              </div>
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <span fxFlex="50%" >header 2</span>
                  <span fxFlex="50%">text 2</span>
              </div>
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <span fxFlex="50%" >header 3</span>
                  <span fxFlex="50%">text 3</span>
              </div>
              <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                  <span fxFlex="50%" >header 4</span>
                  <span fxFlex="50%">text 4</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="none stretch">
                <div fxFlex="1 1 auto" fxLayout="column">
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%">
                        <div fxLayout="row">
                            <span fxFlex="50%">header 5</span>
                            <span fxFlex="50%">text 5</span>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column">
                            <div fxLayout="row">
                                <span fxFlex="50%">header 6</span>
                                <span fxFlex="50%">text 6</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column">
                            <div fxLayout="row">
                                <span fxFlex="50%">header 7</span>
                                <span fxFlex="50%">text 7</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column">
                            <div fxLayout="row">
                                <span fxFlex="50%">header 8</span>
                                <span fxFlex="50%">text 8</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="100%">
                        content goes here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space-taker"></div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Note that the `<div class="space-taker"></div>` is purely there to account for the space taken up by the expansion panel toggle in the header, and if it is removed then the text in the header and the content don't line up.

That div is why I am trying to use flex to arrange the contents.

Chrome seems to miscalculate the height of the text in the expansion panel content. Firefox does not display this behaviour.

Chrome 72.0.3626.121:

[image: Chrome 72.0.3626.121 rendering]

Firefox 65.0.2:

[image: Firefox 65.0.2 rendering]

Note that the height of the span is calculated as 11.25px in Chrome, whereas in Firefox it is correctly 18px.

The problem is exacerbated by having more items in the container.

**UPDATE:** It looks like this was a bug in Chrome 72. This morning I updated to Chrome 73.0.3683.86 and Chrome now has the expected behaviour. However, the accepted answer does fix it in Chrome 72. Here's the bugtracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596743 and the chrome feature page: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6736527476391936

Comment: Logan, your example on Stackbitz looks ok, using the chrome I get 19.09px height

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: What OS are you guys on? I'm on windows 10 1803.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent div of header 5-8, put flex-shrink: 0 or fxFlex="1 0 auto".

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-chrome-squishing-text-c3v5p9

Comment: It looks like I pulled down Chrome 73 and that fixed my original problem, however this does fix it in Chrome 72.